# Mac gcc trying to link against old, nonexistent library

Tags: c, macos

I'm writing a simple C program that uses the TagLib library. I had originally installed the library in /usr/local and compiled and linked my program against it. I've since removed the library completely and am attempting to link against a compiled version of the library in another location. The problem is when I compile my program now, it compiles cleanly, but when attempting to run it, my program is looking for the library that used to exist in /usr/local/lib instead of the new location. For example, my code and the new TagLib library is in /Users/mdi/Code/tag.

I'm compiling my program like this:

```
cc main.c -Wall -I./taglib/bindings/c -o tag -L./taglib/bindings/c/.libs -ltag_c
```

Like I said, the compile completes with no errors or warnings. But when attempting to run the binary, I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libtag_c.0.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/mdi/Code/tag/./tag
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap
```

Running 'otool -L' on the binary shows this:

```
tag:
/usr/local/lib/libtag_c.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.1)
```

Why is it still trying to use the TagLib library that no longer even exists in /usr/local/lib and more importantly, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys. Actually, unfortunately neither of these solutions worked. After more digging around, I noticed that the newly built libs were getting the old path as well, as reported by 'otool -L'. I managed to fix this by using `install_name_tool -id /new/path/to/lib newly_built_lib` on the libs after they were already built.

This seems to fix the problem, but I'm still curious as to why this old path to the lib is still hanging around even after it has been completely removed (no dangling symlinks). I also tried `sudo update_dyld_shared_cache -force` without success. But thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Okay, now I think I'm starting to understand. I think what is happening is the install path (where the lib would be installed if I was to do a `make install`) is what is showing up in the lib as reported by `otool -L`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't develop on Mac, but I believe your problem is that your library isn't located in your default dynamic link path.  It varies on platform, but /usr/local/lib is a common one amongst them, and that's why it's showing up as the path your linking with at runtime.

You can change your default search path for shard libraries, but I'm uncertain of how to do this on a Mac.  You should also be able to set the environment variable DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH within your session to force dyld to search other directories before searching the default directories.

```
%>  export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/library:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Adding directories to your default search path at a system level is better than the environment variable solution above, but I'm unaware of how to do this on the Mac.

***Edit:***

After a little searching, I found this [link](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-06-linking-and-install-names.html) that you'll likely find helpful.

Comment: Same thinking as my solution... this is the one to test first. If this works, then setting the `rpath` to the library as outlined in my answer is likely to be the permanent solution.

Answer (score 1):

First, are you sure there are no dangling symlinks in /usr/local/bin ? Then, I don't know how that library is compiled/linked so I can't tell you how to do this, but you can try adding the `-rpath` linker option. For example:

```
gcc -o libtag_c.0.dylib ... -Wl,-rpath,/Users/mdi/Code/tag
```

That option adds an explicit search path for the library and the runtime linker will then search at that path for the library.