# gcc Linking/Segfault issue on OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, gcc, linker

So a little backstory for what's going on. I'm currently working on building a number of things (including SDL, SDL_image, etc.) and linking it all together in a single executable, and doing it manually. I am making my own custom makefile and only using the command line, not Xcode. (I dislike Xcode) So far I've succeeded in all of this, but I want to start putting Lua scripting on top of my code, so I'm now compiling luajit2.0 and attempting to link that in as well.

However, while SDL worked fine and I could get a window open with a loaded image, luajit refused to link in correctly. It was giving me the dyld: Library not loaded... message, referencing /usr/local/lib even though it not only doesn't exist there, but gcc is given -L on the command line to the folder which holds my built luajit. Using otool -L on my binary gives that directory, even though, again, it doesn't even exist there.

While attempting to google this problem, I came across a solution that gave me this command: `` install_name_tool -id `pwd`/install/lib/libluajit-5.1.dylib install/lib/libluajit-5.1.dylib ``. ([from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979821/mac-gcc-trying-to-link-against-old-nonexistent-library)) After rebuilding the binary, and using otool on it, I now saw the correct directory for the library. Now, however, while it doesn't give me the dyld error, it gives me a segfault the moment I use a luajit function. (luaL_newstate, specifically)

The command to build my binary is as follows:

```
gcc -g -Wall -arch x86_64 -framework Cocoa -Iinstall/include -Linstall/lib src/native/main.c -lluajit-5.1.2.0.0 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2 -lSDL2main -lpng -lz -o game
```

libluajit-5.1.2.0.0.dylib, and all the corresponding symlinks are in install/lib. lua include files are in install/include. What's going wrong here? I'm very confused and would like to just have this start working. I'd rather wrestle code than wrestle gcc and OS X.

EDIT: Per request, the previous error I got before the current "Segmentation fault: 11" error that I'm getting was basically this:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/luajit-5.1.2.dylib
  Referenced from: <my application, forgot this exact bit>
  Reason: image not found
```

And if I did otool -L game I got:

```
MacBook-Air:old freezerburn$ otool -L game
game:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 19.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libluajit-5.1.2.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.0.0)
    /Users/freezerburn/Dropbox/Code/lua_engine/old/install/lib/libSDL2_image-1.2.0.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.5.0)
    /Users/freezerburn/Dropbox/Code/lua_engine/old/install/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /Users/freezerburn/Dropbox/Code/lua_engine/old/install/lib/libpng15.15.dylib (compatibility version 30.0.0, current version 30.0.0)
    /Users/freezerburn/Dropbox/Code/lua_engine/old/install/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.7)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

Even though libluajit was in ./install/lib.

Comment: It's always wise to post the exact error message when asking about an error message...

Comment: My current error message is, literally: Segmentation fault: 11. I figured that saying I was having segfaults was sufficient. I can edit that in if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shared library has an install path. This means you *must* build and install with the proper PREFIX, see the install docs. Or consider linking with the static LuaJIT library -- loading dynamic libraries from non-system locations is a can of worms.

The segfault is due to not following the [LuaJIT embedding instructions](http://luajit.org/install.html#embed) for OSX/x64.

Comment: Gah, I feel like an idiot. I thought I'd read through the embedding instructions. I completely missed that one, highly specific bit for this exact type of computer. Thanks a ton for pointing that out, Lua is working now that I have that bit added to the linking step :) Also I do set the PREFIX correctly when building, and all the libs/includes/etc. get dumped into $(PROJECT)/install

Answer (score 0):

Why not make life easy for yourself and use [Macports](http://macports.org):

1. Install macports
2. `$ xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`
3. `$ sudo port selfupdate`
4. `$ sudo port install libsdl_image luajit`

This will install the ports you request and any dependencies.

You can then concentrate on your project with the knowledge that a qualified team is looking after all that other stuff.

Comment: While I appreciate the advice (and I do know about Macports and homebrew), that's not what I'm looking to do right now. This is eventually intended to be compilable across multiple platforms, and Macports (obviously) only works on a Mac :) I'm trying to keep the entire build completely self-contained for this reason